# How do I execute a custom function in an angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the directive from angular smart table for adding a checkbox selection to the rows of the table shown below. I want to be able to execute a custom function when I click on the checkbox. Is this possible ? I basically need to store the rowid or another property of the rows when the checkbox is clicked.

```
app.directive('csSelect', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        template: '<input type="checkbox"/>',
        scope: {
            row: '=csSelect'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            element.bind('change', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.select(scope.row, 'multiple');
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('row.isSelected', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === true) {
                    element.parent().addClass('st-selected');
                } else {
                    element.parent().removeClass('st-selected');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**EDIT**

The way this directive is used as follows:

`<td cs-select="row"></td>`

note that if I add ng-click to the `td` element to check for a clicked row, it does not matter whether I click on the checkbox. As soon as I click anywhere inside the td element, it acts as that I clicked on the row. So that's not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive('csSelect', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        template: '<input type="checkbox"/>',
        scope: {
            row: '=csSelect',
            myFunc: '&cs-func'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            element.bind('change', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.select(scope.row, 'multiple');
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('row.isSelected', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === true) {
                    element.parent().addClass('st-selected');
                    scope.myFunc();
                } else {
                    element.parent().removeClass('st-selected');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

then

```
<td cs-select="row" cs-func='alert("hello")'></td>
```

Comment: Tried this now but checkbox is not visible for some reason

Comment: Works great! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-click` to the directives template.

```
template: "<input type='checkbox' ng-click='myFunc()'/>"
```

And in link/controller of directive:

```
scope.myFunc = function() { //Code };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ng-click="controller.function()"
```

Comment: That unfortunately does not solve my problem, see the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can expose functions to your template html in your directive by adding them to the `scope` argument injected into your `link` function.

You can use this for your change handler, and you can use `ngClass` to evaluate whether to attach the css class to your input.

Try something along these lines:

```
return {
  // ...,
  template: '<input ng-change="changeHandler()" ng-class="{'st-selected': row.isSelected}">',
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, parentCtrl) {
    scope.changeHandler = function () {
      // parentCtrl.whatever(scope.row);
    };
  }
};
```

One thing your input is missing is an `ngModel`. I'm not sure what all is going on in your `stTable` directive, but you can and probably should bind your checkbox directive to a model. `row.isSelected` springs to mind.